# In C++, how to make it such that the constructor can have different types of arguments?

Tags: c++, constructor

I want to define a constructor for a class CLS. And I want to include different situations in my definition of the constructor. For example, I want the constructor to work when the argument is void:
CLS::CLS();

or when the argument is an integer,
CLS::CLS(int a);

How do I do this?

Comment: Write two constructors

Comment: You can also take advantage of [default arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments). eg. `CLS(int a = 0);`

Comment: Please consult Google before asking questions on Stack Overflow. You're probably getting downvoted because a simple search could find the answer: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS594US594&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2B%2B%20constructors%20with%20different%20arguments

Comment: @KeithM Thanks and I will keep that in mind. I actually searched it before I ask here. Probably I did not search it in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question actually is too generic, in my opinion.

A general answer is [function overloading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm).

In short you can simply write two different function (method in that case) with the same name, but different argument. You can specify a different body for each of them. For example:

```
class CLS {
 public:
   CLS(int n) {
     // do something
   }

   CLS(char c) {
     // do something else
   }
};
```

Then you can simply construct an object:

```
// ... somewhere
CLS object1(12);  // 12 is a int, then the first 'ctor will be invoked
CLS object2('b');  // 'b' is a char, the second 'ctor will be invoked, instead.
```

---

A "move advance" answer requires the usage of *template*.

In short you can write a single constructor which accept a *generic* type as argument and specify a behaviour in case that type follow certain traits.

```
class CLS {
 public:
   template<typename T>
   CLS(T t) {
     if (std::is_arithmetic<T>::value) {
       // do something if the type is an arithmetic
     } else {
       // do something else
     }
   }
};
```

That approach could be useful when you can "generalize" (for almost all the body) the behaviour of your constructor, and you want to aggregate different type.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to take advantage of [Default Arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments). For example

```
#include <iostream>

class example
{
public:
    int val;
    example(int in = 0): val(in)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    example a(10);
    example b;

    std::cout << a.val << "," << b.val << std::endl;
}
```

will output

```
10,0
```